# file uploading thorough form to email rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, email-attachments

hi i am trying to upload the PDF document from the form and directly to the controller and all i need is the full path of file is uploading.i was using remortipart but i cannot use it because its rails 5 project.and i am only getting path of my project directory is there any way i can get full path to file from any where in my computer.And i am trying to send file directly into email without saving it anywhere

```
         <div class="small-dialog-content">
        <%= form_tag send_mail_jobs_path(id:@job.id)  %>
            <div class="form">
                <h5>Upload CV </h5>
                <%= file_field_tag :cv, accept: 'application/pdf'  %>
              </div>

              <p class="form-row">.
                <%= submit_tag "Send CV" %>
              </p>
        </div>
```

in jobs controller

def send_mail

```
@sender=params[:email]
@message=params[:message]
job=Job.find(params[:id])
email=job.user.email
@file= File.absolute_path(params[:cv])
@subject= "CV for job",

Cv_Send.welcome_email(email,@sender,@subject,@message,@file).deliver
redirect_to jobs_path, notice: 'you had applied sucessfully'
end
```

in my mailer

class Cv_Send < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'
  def welcome_email(email ,sender,subject,message,file)
    attachments.inline['gul.pdf']  = File.read(file)
    mail(to: email,sender:sender ,subject:subject, message: message,file:file )
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

Whereas I know you should create a temporary file with some index on it such as

> user_id_file_name.pdf

somewhere in your local directory and then try to send it through mail. 
After a successful delivery of mail you can delete it and also please remember that you should keep that pdf storing directory in **.gitignore**